# Why bitfields have to be integer?

Tags: c, integer, bit-fields

Every book I searched, every tutorial on the internet and every q&a on SO says, that bitfields have to be integer type. Why is that?

Comment: Ask yourself the opposite question.  Every book I searched, every tutorial on the internet says that bitfields can't be floating point types, strings or complex objects.  Why is that?

Comment: What would it mean to have a floating-point bit-field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's ask the converse question:

- What types other than an integer type could a bit field be?

Let's review the options:

1. `void`: not a value — wouldn't work.
2. Pointers: but pointers on a machine are fixed size; you can't use 13 bits of a pointer and expect it to mean anything.
3. Structures, unions: but then you aren't dealing with simple fields.
4. That leaves `float` or `double`, but those are carefully designed formats and you can't simply use 13 bits out of a `double` (or `float`) and expect it to mean anything.

So, after you've gone through the options, you are left with the various types of integer: `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` (in signed and unsigned forms), and `_Bool`.  Of these options, the standard specifies that you can use `_Bool`, `unsigned int`, `signed int` and 'plain' `int`:

> ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.2.1 **Structure and union type specifiers**
>
> ¶5 A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed
>   int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. It is
>   implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted.

The behaviour of 'plain' `int` is implementation defined: it may be signed or unsigned (roughly like 'plain' `char` can be signed or unsigned).  So, the comment by [jxh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315052/jxh) is correct; I was careless quoting too many types (but I've rephrased things so that it isn't so misleading).

Note that most of the behaviour of bit-fields is implementation defined; beyond the notation, there is very little that is specified by the standard.

Comment: For some reason, it is only standard for `_Bool`, `int`, and `unsigned int`. All others are implementation defined.

Comment: As always, it seems so obvious now, when I realized how hard would it be to manipulate on floats to change specific bits, while integers are straight forward.

Comment: C99 does provide support for hexadecimal constants to specify floating point values, but those are a source code concept; it would be hard to handle them at runtime (you'd have to use `snprintf()` and `sscanf()`, probably). I'm not sure where to list `_Complex`; it could be composite like structures and unions. I also didn't mention arrays, but arrays have a base type and it doesn't make much sense to try manipulating arrays of bits because there isn't really a bit type in C. Etc. You're right; once you go through the alternatives, it is fairly obvious that integers are the only real option.

Answer (score 3):

Integers are a simple set of weighted bits. They are quiet, unassuming, and lend themselves readily to bit manipulation.

Almost every other data type is subject to some sort of interpretation: floating point numbers have two parts, a mantissa and an exponent; strings are ... well, strings of bytes (or Unicode values).  A structure, or a pointer to an array, can represent almost anything.

As an example, I can easily store 32 bits in an integer, and retrieve them like so (c-like pseudocode):

```
int GetBit(int field, int position)
{
    return field & 1 << position;
}
```

Where the return value is either 1 or 0, stored in an integer.

A byte (eight bits) is sort of the lowest common denominator in a computer system; computers won't let you retrieve quantities of bits smaller than that directly, and most computers nowadays retrieve bits in multi-byte quantities. A 32 bit computer retrieves... well, 32 bits at a time; a 32 bit integer, which is where our conversation began.

Comment: @CarlNorum - Its the rest of the attributes of floating points that would make it difficult.  Would weighting of each position not be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is just how bit-fields are defined to be, they can only take on (certain) integer types and are interpreted as integer values.

C.11 §6.7.2.1 ¶5:

> A bit-ﬁeld shall have a type that is a qualiﬁed or unqualiﬁed version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-deﬁned type. It is implementation-deﬁned whether atomic types are permitted.

C.11 §6.7.2.1 ¶10:

> A bit-ﬁeld is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the speciﬁed number of bits. If the value 0 or 1 is stored into a nonzero-width bit-ﬁeld of type `_Bool`, the value of the bit-ﬁeld shall compare equal to the value stored; a `_Bool` bit-ﬁeld has the semantics of a `_Bool`.

If you are wondering about how a bit-field is used, bit-fields are typically used to create a smaller type than what it is based on. And, as the name implies, it is expected the "variables" of that type be useful for bit-manipulation. And bit operations are traditionally, and intuitively, performed with integer types.

Comment: Yeah, that's just a tautology.  It's an integer because the spec says its an integer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I suppose it is, but is there any other answer that doesn't involve speculation?

Comment: @RobertHarvey +1 for finding a good place to use "tautology". However, it is appropriate and conclusive (and comforting) to refer to a standard occasionally, don't you think?

Comment: @ryyker: It just "begs" the question, "why does the spec say it's an integer?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I don't typically speculate on why C is standardized in a certain way. I assume it is traditional, because there is no reason `char` could not be a standardized type for a bit-field, same for the `long`-er integer types as well.

Comment: @jxh "Because it's tradition." :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Uncle.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually all other types (i.e. non-integers) exist in the language mostly because they are (or can be) directly supported by the underlying hardware. That applies, for example, to pointer types and floating-point arithmetic types. The underlying hardware immediately imposes strict format and bit-size requirements on the object representation of the type. It is not possible to change the bit-size of the type and still keep it directly supported by the hardware.

In order to implement such feature as bit-fields for non-integer types the implementation would have to provide software-level support for bit-field versions of those types, i.e. it would have to *emulate* support for such types. This would be rather complicated and inefficient, so the language standard does not include this as a feature. Meanwhile, for integer types this is not difficult to implement with great efficiency.