# struct in union nested - understanding behaviour of type punning

Tags: c++, struct, nested, unions

The following code uses a structure inside a union inside a structure inside a union.

```
#include <cstdio>

union
{
    char abcd[4];
    struct
    {
        unsigned ab : 16;
        union
        {
            unsigned xyz : 8;
            struct
            {
                unsigned x : 3;
                unsigned y : 5;
            };
        };
//      unsigned x : 3;
//      unsigned y : 5;
        unsigned d : 8;
    };
} SpringOnion;

int main ()
{
    SpringOnion.ab = 0xfe57;
    SpringOnion.x = 0x5;
    SpringOnion.y = 0x1c;
    SpringOnion.d = 0xfa;

    printf("%x %x %x\n", SpringOnion.x, SpringOnion.y, SpringOnion.xyz);
    printf("%x %x %x %x\n", SpringOnion.abcd[0], SpringOnion.abcd[1], SpringOnion.abcd[2], SpringOnion.abcd[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled using g++ (also checked with gcc) and got the following output on running:

```
5 1c e5
57 fffffffe 0 0
```

Is that the expected output?

On defining the union in the following manner:

```
union
{
    char abcd[4];
    struct
    {
        unsigned ab : 16;
        union
        {
            unsigned xyz;
            struct
            {
                unsigned x : 3;
                unsigned y : 5;
            };
        }c : 8;
        unsigned d : 8;
    };
} SpringOnion;
```

I get the compilation error:
`error: bit-field ‘c’ with non-integral type ‘<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::<unnamed union>’`
which, on checking up, gives answers which seem to me to be not perfectly relatable.
The answer by Jonathan Leffler https://stackoverflow.com/a/18730706/7920584 points out by saying:

> Structures, unions: but then you aren't dealing with simple fields.

But then what kind of field should I be using? Is there something else that can meet my expectations?

Expectation:-
I expect the output to be:

```
5 1c e5
57 fffffffe ffffffe5 fffffffa
```

Which is similar to what I get upon removing the nested union and using the `x :3;` and `y :5;` directly in the main struct.

May I know why I am expecting wrong?

Comment: It would help guide our answers if you explained *why* you have the expectation you do.

Comment: *Is that the expected output?*  No.  There is no one correct "expected output".  Bit-fields are entirely [implementation-dependent](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p11): "An implementation may allocate **any addressable storage unit** large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is **implementation-defined**. "

Comment: (cont) "The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is **implementation-defined**. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is **unspecified**."

Comment: Do choose one language.  C and C++ have a moderately large body of shared syntax, but also significant differences, including in some of the details of how they interpret some of the elements of that shared syntax.

Comment: Generally speaking, do not use bit fields in code that you intend to be portable.  Their behavior is much less specified than most people suppose, and some common assumptions about that behavior are wrong in some common implementations.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "It would help guide our answers if you explained why you have the expectation you do"
I had that expectation until a while ago. Simply because, where I work, type punning in this way was used all over the place by someone I would have considered better than me. Now I realise I need to stop doing that specially since I am using Qt, which is supposed to be for portability.

Comment: That's not what I meant by my question, @Ulterno, but the conclusion you seem now to have drawn about bit fields is a reasonable one.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You just made me realise how bad my code is for the application I am coding for. Definitely not using union type-punning from now on.

Comment: @JohnBollinger May I know if there is another way I can do a similar thing without having to use ">>" bitwise shifters all over the place and type cast for each and every variable?
I had never used unions this way before I saw the implementation in my current place's codebase. And am soon going to stop using it again.
Is it a good idea to typecast a structure into another variable? But wait, then again the order of allocation would be undefined in case the code is ported

Comment: @Ulterno, you cannot convert a structure to an integer type, if that's what you're thinking.  Not in C, and especially not in C++.  As far as bitwise operations go, have you considered simply not packing multiple logically-distinct values into the same integer?

Comment: @JohnBollinger " have you considered simply not packing multiple logically-distinct values into the same integer?"
The problem is that, that's the requirement. Though of course, the data type I need to pack it into is a QByteArray and not an int array, and I hopefully won't be doing any arithmetic operations on it.
In the end, I need to either send them to a device api in the form of an array of unsigned short array or send it through the network as a datagram

Comment: @Ulterno, if you need to generate and consume data packed into fields with sub-byte boundaries, in a way that is portable across systems with different ABIs, then shifting and bitwise arithmetic is what you need to do.  It might be that you need that only for a subset of the members, but bit fields are not a portable solution.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "then shifting and bitwise arithmetic is what you need to do." - I think this should be considered as a part of the answer of the above question.

Comment: Interesting. If your expectation was correct, you would have found an answer to my recent question [Does union of bit fields make any sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71056713). That would have been an example where a bit field inside an `union` would make sense. But the fact it doesn't work as you expected (I am not surprised at all) confirms to me that although bit fields in union are legal, they are always useless in practice.

Comment: @prapin I would say that the way I typed the syntax in the question above would not even be making the union a part of the bit field. And the syntax that would do so, https://www.codepile.net/pile/m3vdrP7D would give an error `error: bit-field ‘GX2’ with non-integral type ‘hhc’`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> printf("%x %x %x\n", SpringOnion.x, SpringOnion.y, SpringOnion.xyz);
>                                                                ^^^
> printf("%x %x %x %x\n", SpringOnion.abcd[0], SpringOnion.abcd[1], SpringOnion.abcd[2], SpringOnion.abcd[3]);
>                                     ^^^^                 ^^^^                 ^^^^                 ^^^^
> ```

Here, you read from an inactive member of a union. You aren't allowed to do that in C++. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Is that the expected output?

There is no portable expectation for the output. Even if we were to assume that there is a reasonable behaviour defined by the language implementation for reading an inactive union member, there's still no precise definition for allocation of bitfields in the language. That is implementation defined in most regards (in practice, it's determined by the ABI, which varies across different systems).

---

Furthermore, you have anonymous structs in your union. Anonymous structs are not allowed in C++. The program is ill-formed.

Comment: Isn't that part supposed to be implementation defined and work with "type punning"? Which it is in fact doing, at least in that case. As it simply gave the output 0xe5, which is the correct value. My problem lies in the second printf call, where abcd[2] and abcd[3] don't do their job.

Comment: @Ulterno Accessing inactive member of a union is not implementation defined. Its undefined behaviour in C++ (except for an exceptional case that doesn't apply here).

Comment: Thanks, I will try making some changes and see how it can work.
Though, if I can't use it for type punning in this way, should I simply be typecasting each and every variable and adding it to the other variable separately, or is there a better option?
--I need to do that for a 60+ array, which will be taking values of many different sizes.

Comment: @Ulterno Your description is too vague for me to tell you what you should do.

Comment: I need to take multiple inputs from the ui (using Qt and most of them have functions to convert to int) and add them into a QByteArray (which can be done from a char array), making them align to specific locations inside the bytes. e.g. there might be some data to be stored as 2 bits of byte[1] and another as the next 6 bits of byte[1]. And the smallest variable I can think of for the input data before adding to the array is uint8 (quint8 in this case)

Comment: Accessing inactive member of a union is defined by C standard. True, not in C++, but in practice all compilers do not distinguish C and C++ behavior for union type punning.